How can we get the contents of an occluded window using Rust
I hope someone can give me some Pointers. I want to use Rust to call the Windows api for a feature that fetches the contents of an occluded window. I tried DGI method, but BitBlt method could not get the contents of the occluded window, I tried PrintWindow, PrintWindow can get the contents of the occluded window, but PrintWindow gets a large part of the image is transparent.
Here's my code
unsafe fn window_shot(title: String) -> Result<ImageBuffer<Rgba<u8>, Vec<u8>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let handle: HWND = get_window_handle(title);
    let source_dc: HDC = GetDC(None);
    println!("{}", source_dc.0 as usize);
    let rect = get_window_loc(handle);
    let width = rect.right - rect.left;
    let height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    let mut shot_data = vec![0u8; (width * height * 4) as usize];
    let compatible_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(source_dc);
    let h_bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(source_dc, width, height);
    SelectObject(compatible_dc, h_bitmap);
    if PrintWindow(handle, compatible_dc, PW_CLIENTONLY) == FALSE {
        return Err("PrintWindow failed".into());
    }
    // BitBlt(compatible_dc, 0, 0, width, height, source_dc, rect.left, rect.top, SRCCOPY)
    //     .expect("BitBlt fail.");
    let shot_data_ptr = shot_data.as_mut_ptr() as *mut core::ffi::c_void;
    if GetBitmapBits(h_bitmap, width * height * 4, shot_data_ptr) == 0 {
        return Err("GetBitmapBits failed".into());
    }
    DeleteObject(h_bitmap).expect("DeleteObject fail.");
    DeleteDC(compatible_dc).expect("DeleteDC fail.");
    ReleaseDC(handle, source_dc);
    ImageBuffer::<Rgba<u8>, _>::from_raw(width as u32, height as u32, shot_data)
        .ok_or_else(|| "Failed to create image buffer".into())
        .map(|mut image| {
            image.pixels_mut().for_each(|pixel| {
                let r = pixel[0];
                let g = pixel[1];
                let b = pixel[2];
                let a = pixel[3];
                *pixel = Rgba([b, g, r, a]);
            });
            image
        })
}

This is my resulting plot.


You can see that most of my screenshot is missing.
I am not familiar with Windows api. Is there any other solution that can realize this function for me? I need to be able to intercept the contents of the blocked window, and it would be better to convert it into a video stream.

You'll have to use Windows.Graphics.Capture. See Robert Mikhayelyan's screenshot-rs for a sample implementation.

For video recording see displayrecorder.

@IInspectable Thank you very much for your reply. These two warehouses really solved the problem that I wanted to intercept the window content. I wonder if the two repositories can be combined to complete a video stream that captures the contents of the specified window? Looking forward to your reply.

Probably, with minimal effort. Ultimately, you'll have to replace the CreateForMonitor call with CreateForWindow. I don't think you'll need to do anything else (ignoring the command line argument parsing).
